# How to Get Category from Rss Fedd

Tags: php, rss

```
<title>demo title</title>
<guid isPermaLink="false">demo link</guid>
<link>demo link 2</link>
<description>demo description</description>
<category><![CDATA[category]]></category>
<dc:creator>demouser</dc:creator>
<pubDate>timestamp</pubDate>
```

I want to get Category Field from the above Rss
i have got everything from that RSS only category is not coming
i have tried with `print_r` but category is not printing in the array

can any1 tell me how to get that category value ?

Comment: Are you using simple_xml_load ?

Comment: i am using this method
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

Comment: You need to edit the question to show how you are getting the rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple_xml_load func.

```
$xml = simple_xml_load("http://host");
print_r($xml);
echo $xml->category;
```

Comment: am getting eveything except category with this function and its simplexml_load_file

Comment: So, its wrong xml document. Try using regex. preg_match("#<category>(.*)</category>#", $xml, $match);

Comment: That means that no <category> tags you receive.

Comment: but there is category tags in that rss
i am getting
<category><![CDATA[abcd]]></category>

i just want abcd from that rss